# Как сделать так, чтобы бот пополнял опыт пользователя за отправленное сообщение в чат сервера?

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlite, discord.py, sqlite3

Пишу на `discord.py` своего бота. Я не знаю, как сделать, чтобы бот пополнял репутацию пользователя в `sqlite3` `базы_данных.db`. В таблице я всё записал, мне нужна сама команда.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду команду библиотеки sqlite3 или же discord.py?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Допустим, наша SQL таблица выглядит так:

```
users_ranking

user_id INT
user_xp INT
```

Добавим в нашем боте ивент `on_message`, который срабатывает при отправке любого сообщения (вот [ссылка](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.on_message) на документацию).

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    # Объявим переменные
    user_id = message.author.id
    xp_for_message = len(message) # опыт за сообщение равен количеству символов в сообщении

    # Делаем запрос к БД
    cursor.execute(f'UPDATE users_ranking SET user_xp=user_xp+{xp_for_message} WHERE user_id={user_id})
    conn.commit()
```

Comment: Хочу заметить что он не только работает в чате сервера, но и в лс с ботом